# jQuery to change content in div based on scroll position

Tags: jquery, blogs

I am building a blog page in Wordpress and adding a sidebar that points to the current post. I'd like to fill that sidebar with the date of the current post using jQuery. It's only an idea so I don't have any code. But it would function like this:

[image]

As you scroll down the page the date (or other info) would change based on which div you were next to. It also has to work in a blog setting meaning each div can potentially be a different height.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have information about the date stored anywhere or do you want just to count from the top?

Comment: I'm going to be using wordpress, so I'll be taking information from each post. Things like the date, author, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do not know where you want to get the date from, so, just an example.. http://jsfiddle.net/Nsubt/

```
$(window).on("scroll resize", function(){
    var pos=$('#date').offset();
    $('.post').each(function(){
        if(pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && 
           pos.top < $(this).next().offset().top)
        {
            // any way you want to get the date
            $('#date').html($(this).html()); 
            return; //break the loop
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
});
​
```

Div on the right could have a fixed position or you can update its absolute position in the block working with `scroll` and `resize` events.

Comment: Cherry, this def puts me on the right track! I am going to have the date in the post description itself and I will simply pull from that.Great answer! Can't wait to try it out.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
});
This is not needed.

Could you please explain how could i do $('#date').html($(this).html()); when page is reloaded on some kind of position. I mean it works just fine, but when i reload the page which is scrolled - it takes the first value while you don`t scroll to the another .post

Comment: @RooticalV. Does triggering the scroll not work? I'm working on something similar.