# Changing a div class depending on where window is

Tags: jquery

Here is my setup: http://jsfiddle.net/REGUs/

As you can see by clicking on the menu on the left, the page scrolls to the relevant information and the menu item changes its appearance to a white background etc.

I would like the page to check where abouts it is and then update the css on the list respectively so that if the page is looking at the second heading the menu changes the second headings css to the style it would be had they clicked it. I know this is quite wordy and probably doesn't make much sense and im sorry.

Here is how i thought it would work:

I don't know how many headings are on each page (i do in theory but there are a lot of pages and i would rather have something dynamic). So i would use `$("h2").length` to check the amount of headers. Then perhaps have a loop to get the distances of each of these (stored in an array?), then every time window scrolls, it starts loading or changes size, a function will capture where the screen is and then updates the css. If this is how you would solve it could you help me put it together, if there is another better way (probably is as i don't really use javascript) can you please let me know.

thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have you checked out Bootstrap? I haven't used it but I plan to, it sounds like it does some similar stuff - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix - look at the menu on the left hand siode and how it changes depending on where you are on the page

Comment: that's the effect i'm after yeah, I just thought it could be done with a few lines of code

Comment: I imagine it can, I was just being lazy. Bootstraps got loads of other handy things as well, just one to always be aware of I think :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you dont want everything from bootstrap here is what you need to do

http://jsfiddle.net/6t83p/1/ some time spent on it but its always fun :)

```
    $('.selectedNav').css( 'background-color', 'white');
$('.selectedNav').css( 'border-right', 'none');

$('.servicesNavItem').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', 'white');
    $(this).parent().css( 'border-right', 'none');
    $('.selectedNav').css( 'background-color', '#eeeeee');
    $('.selectedNav').css( 'border-right', '1px solid #c7c7c7');
    $('.selectedNav').toggleClass("selectedNav");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("selectedNav");
});

var y = $('.servicesLeft').offset().top - 50;
    $(window).scroll( function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > y)
        $('.servicesLeft').addClass('floating');
    else
        $('.servicesLeft').removeClass('floating');
    });

$('#sideNav li a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
/***** ADDED THE FOLLOWING CODE ******/
// get positions of all linked href
var x = {};
$('#sideNav a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    x[href] = $('#'+href).offset().top;
});

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    var current_top = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log(current_top);
    var active = '';
    var min_value = 9999999;
    $.each(x, function(index, value) { 
         // some big value
        if(value >= current_top && value < min_value)
        {
            console.log(min_value);
            min_value = value;
            active = index;
        }
    });

    $('#sideNav li').removeAttr('style');
    $('#sideNav a[href="#'+active+'"]').parent('li').css({'background-color': 'white', 'border-right-style': 'none'});
});
```

Comment: nice code... but theres a bug in the navigation now and the active state. wbr

Comment: fixed that bug :) instead of > do >=

Comment: That is great thanks! Just a little nit pick though, is there a way to make it register at the top of the window rather than the bottom? i.e the css changes when the header first comes into view, i'd rather it changed while at the top of the screen?

Comment: @Rishabh I have found a bug, It changes to the next item in the list when the last one goes past the screen, but just because you can no longer see the title doesn't mean that you are on the next set of data. In the fiddle i have made the second paragraph really long and you can see when you are over the second one on the menu the third on is highlighted, any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/6t83p/2/

Answer (score 1):

i guess this post will would help you

[jQuery to change content in div based on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387452/jquery-to-change-content-in-div-based-on-scroll-position#)

**Happy coding :)**