# How can I change page during mouse scrolling?

Tags: javascript, url, web, scroll

I want to chane my website homepage to another (with another URL) during mouse scrolling. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this.. try something like this out..

1. [jQuery to change content in div based on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387452/jquery-to-change-content-in-div-based-on-scroll-position)
2. http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-horizonal-scroll-demos-plugins/